# issues in Ajax pagination

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've done ajax pagination in codeigniter. Records are dividing by 10 when I click next page button the page is automatically reloading. In localhost the coding is working fine, but in live server it's not working....  kindly help me.... This is my Coding:

```
<script>
var page_number=0;
var total_page =null;
var sr =0;
var sr_no =0;
var getReport = function(page_number){
    if(page_number==0)
    {
        $("#previous").prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#previous").prop('disabled', false);
    }
    if(page_number==(total_page-1))
    {
        $("#next").prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#next").prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $("#page_number").text(page_number+1);
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/admin/pagination",
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:'page_number='+page_number,

        success:function(data)
        {
            window.mydata = data;
            total_page= mydata[0].TotalRows;
            $("#total_page").text(total_page);
            var record_par_page = mydata[0].Rows;
            ............ // here m getting the values
            ......... // here m getting the values
            $.each(record_par_page, function (key, data) 
            {
                sr =(key+1);    
                $(".tb").append('<tr class='+r_class+'><td class="no-print"><input type="checkbox" class="idRow chk_each" name="chk<?PHP echo $po_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $po_id; ?>" <?php echo set_checkbox('chk'.$po_id,$po_id); ?>>   </td><td>'+data.created_date+'</td><td>........displaying values.........</td></tr>');
            });
        }
    });
};

  $(document).ready(function(e){
    getReport(page_number);
    console.log(sr);
    $("#next").on("click", function(){
        $(".tb").html("");
        page_number = (page_number+1);
        getReport(page_number);
        console.log(sr);
    });
    $("#previous").on("click", function(){
        $(".tb").html("");
        page_number = (page_number-1);
        getReport(page_number);
    });
    $("#search").on('keyup', function(){
        var str = $.trim($(this).val());
        search(str);
    });
});
```

Comment: i think you forgot to suppress the click event which is generated. you can use `event.preventDefault()` function

Comment: Whats the error your getting in console?

Comment: @cerlin Boss: I used event.preventdefault function.. its working fine thank you. but in localhost its working without giving this function what is the difference

Comment: i am not sure how its working in your localhost. All i could think of is the event is getting killed. You can use [visual event](https://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) to see the events attached to those links and see if there is any events attached which is killing the event itself. hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the above discussions in  comment the issue raised because of not suppress the clcik fucntion.
Solution to it 
use `event.preventDefault()`